# Delete table on button click

Tags: vba, ms-access

I created a form that imports a csv file as a new table called "ImportTable". I have queries to look at the data.

Once finished with the data I want to delete the table entirely (as part of the client workflow requirements). I'm stuck on how to apply a delete_table function to an on click event.

I put together the below function to delete the table. How can I apply this to an on click event?

The button name is: cmdDeleteImportTable_Click()

```vb
Public Function table_exists(tblName As String) As Boolean

'Returns True if table exists in current DB. Else False

Dim tdf As TableDef
For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If StrComp(tblName, tdf.Name) = 0 Then
        table_exists = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next tdf
End Function


Public Function delete_table(tblName As String) As Boolean
'Returns true if the table is deleted or if the table does not exist

On Error GoTo errHandler

If table_exists(tblName) Then
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tblName
End If
delete_table = True
ExitSuccess:
    Exit Function
errHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    Resume ExitSuccess

End Function

Sub Test()
Const Names_Table = "ImportTable"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Debug.Print delete_table(Names_Table)
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems correct.

All you need to do now is add it a button. In Access Forms you have to select the button, then in **Events** tab, you have **On Click**. Select it and choose code.

This will create an event handler for the click event. Inside this event handler, you can call your code to import data or delete your table.

Further detais [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/use-a-command-button-to-start-an-action-or-a-series-of-actions-c7bf2827-2f3e-42b8-83d6-6c4f0de78990)

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for the answer, I had gotten as far adding the button, the part where I'm getting stuck is how to call the function above.  I had tried the below, but returned compile error: Argument not optional.      `Private Sub cmdDeleteImportTable_Click()
Call delete_table
End Sub`

Comment: Realised I was calling the wrong function -- I called the Test() Sub and it worked! Cheers